# Cropping images based on Kinect coordinate system?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, kinect

How could you convert the kinect coordinate system such as

```
 (0.902157,  -0.054221,  1.002355)
```

To just a normal x and y coordinate based on the images, where (0,0) starts at the top left of the image instead of using the Kinect coordinate system?

Comment: get the minimum (x,y,z) coordinates and translate coords matrices by the opposite?

Comment: It is not clear for me what you are asking for but if you want these coordinates to be the (0,0) then you need to add those values to ALL the other coordinates. Also to plot them "right" into the screen, you feed **X** as it is but each **Y** should be fed as `Image.Height - Y` as the actual Y

Comment: use the Kinect v2 SDK features to save the calibrations maps - it is indeed possible to convert this